# Scroll not working in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, spinner, scrollview

I am trying to scroll to a substring in a string of 1000 lines. I notice a lag in the scroll and UI thread. So I thought to use a AsyncTask but as its executed I get the text but not scroll. Here is my code

```
 private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            SharedPreferences score = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            int chapter_number_bookmark = score.getInt("chapter_number", 89);
            int verse_number_bookmark = score.getInt("verse_number", 1);
            GoToFunction(chapter_number_bookmark,verse_number_bookmark);
            return "Executed";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Executed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
    }
```

The GoToFunction

```
public void GoToFunction(int chapter, int verse)
    {
        int scroll_amt;
        final TextView shw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTab);
        SharedPreferences score = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        int chapter_number = chapter;
        int verse_number = verse;
        String verse_number_str = Integer.toString(verse_number);
        SQLiteDatabase as = openOrCreateDatabase("/"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/tamil/verse", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        Cursor a = as.rawQuery("select * from verse"+chapter_number, null);
        a.moveToFirst();
        strTitle = a.getString(a.getColumnIndex("title"));
        final String strContent_book = a.getString(a.getColumnIndex("content"));
        int number = a.getInt(a.getColumnIndex("dialogues"));
        tab.setText("\n\n "+strAthi+strTitle+"\n\n "+strVasa+number+"\n\n "+strContent_book);
        final int offset_dot = strContent_book.indexOf(verse_number_str_dot);
        final int offset_comma = strContent_book.indexOf(verse_number_str_comma);
        a.close();
        as.close();
        if(offset_comma!=-1||offset_dot!=-1)
        {
            if(offset_comma==-1||(offset_dot<offset_comma))
            {
            try
            {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Athiyayam : "+ chapter_number +" Verse : "+ verse_number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            **scroll(offset_dot); //Scroll function**
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Scroll_comma", "Exception", e);
            }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Athiyayam : "+ chapter_number +" Verse :"+ verse_number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                scroll(offset_comma);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e("Scroll", "Exception", e);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Scroll Function

```
public void scroll(final int a)
    {
        final TextView shw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTab);
        try
        {
        mScroll.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int y = shw.getLayout().getLineForOffset(a); // e.g. I want to scroll to line 40
                int n = shw.getLayout().getLineTop(y);
                mScroll.scrollTo(0, n);
            }
        });
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        Log.e("scroll", "error", e);
        }   
    }
```

Here I get the text. But the scroll function doesn't get executed. Also I want to do a spinner activity as the bookmark activity starts and finish as it ends which can be done in PreExecute and PostExecute

Answer (score 0):

paste this code to your layout:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    >

           <!-- "your layout" -->

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I don't think there is problem with the scrollview. It works fine. When I execute the background task then its not scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

From your code you try to update main thread from `doInBackground`.

```
       @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
               ....
            GoToFunction(chapter_number_bookmark,verse_number_bookmark);
            .....
        }
```

You can't do that. I'm sure you get Exception in logcat. If you want to update anyways, do that through Handler

Lets say we have

```
private TextView m_txtLog;    
private ScrollView m_sv;
```

So to scroll to last line should be something like:

```
m_sv.post(new Runnable() { 
  public void run() { 
     m_sv.scrollTo(0, m_txtLog.getHeight());                
     } 
  });
```

If you run it from `Service` or `AsyncTask` use `Handler` like:

```
static final int LOG_MSG = 1;

private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            String txt;
            switch (msg.what) {
            case LOG_MSG:
                txt = msg.obj.toString();
                m_txtLog.append(txt);

                m_sv.post(new Runnable() { 
                    public void run() { 
                        m_sv.scrollTo(0, m_txtLog.getHeight());                 
                    } 
                });     
                break;
            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    };
```

And now we can write from `AsyncTask`:

```
mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(LOG_MSG, "Agent started" + "\n\n"));
```

As you can see `scrollTo` wrapped by handler. By this way it will work.

(Tested)

Comment: I want to scroll to a particular line.. The scroll is working fine without the AsyncTask for smaller lines. When I get 1000 lines I notice a lag and so I had put in AsyncTask which does the process of setting the text but doesn't scroll.

Comment: did you try with Handler?

Answer (score 0):

Using asynctask for scrolling is really not necessary in this case. you can simply run the code in the main thread.  It will work fine. 
because if the user clicks the scrollview while scrolling by asyntask. there will be unexpected behaviour. 
And also specify 
1. `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in your activity manifest of scrollview 
2. In addition to above step - `scrollView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);`

This will use hardware acceleration to your scrollview for smooth scrolling.